How can I add a role to someone while ignoring the permissions of the command user?
My code:
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx, person):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role")
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role"):
        await role.edit(position=10)
    else:
        await guild.create_role(name="role", color=discord.Color(0x000000))
        await role.edit(position=10)
    person = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=person)
    user = ctx.message.author
    await user.add_roles(person, role)

This is supposed to be a command that gives a role to a user, but it doesn't work. When the command %giverole is used, it returns an exception: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
I do not understand why this is happening, because I am using a testing server where I, the owner am using the command.
Is there a way I can fix this? Or, better yet, make the command ignore the permissions of the user altogether?

Your bot need more permissions

The exception does not say that the problem is your permissions when running the program, it says that the Bot itself does not have the permissions to add that role. That is, in the discord role hierarchy, your bot's role is below the role you are trying to add. The role is above rol bot
